# FatalErrorException in PracticeController.php line 0: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must not throw an exception**

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, model, phpmyadmin

I try to get table values using model in laravel 5.4 but i got a error like this

> FatalErrorException in PracticeController.php line 0: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must not throw an exception**

My Model:

Interview.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Interviews extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'interview_schedule';

  protected $primaryKey ='schedule_id';



}
```

My Controller:

PracticeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Interviews;

class PracticeController extends Controller

{
    public function getAll()
    {

    $getinterviews=Interviews::all();

    echo $getinterviews;

    }

}
```

I serach google and stack overflow there is no solution this error. so give solution this process.

Answer (score 0):

The `Interviews::all()` method returns an object.

You cannot `echo` object. 
When you try, this triggers `__toString()` magic method of the object, which try to convert your object to string : [php manual: __toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

If you want to view what is inside this variable, try using provided [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd) helper method like this:

> dd($getinterviews);